# Yii, PHPMailer : how to send an email with HTML and ICS format

Tags: php, email, yii, outlook, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email with HTML and Ics format to gmail, outlook, yahoo, thunderbird, outlook express 2013 and iphone, but i am only able to send ics format to gmail, outlook and yahoo.

**Issue** I am not able to send html format in same mail
I tried with following code

```
public function createScheduleNotification(){

    $from = 'info@careervita.com';
    $fromName = 'info';
    $to = 'testcareervita@outlook.com';
    $subject = 'Invitation for Test Demo';
    $desc = 'THIS IS TEST DEMO INVITAION';
    $uid =  date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand();

    $message =  "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    $message.=  "PRODID:-//Zoho CRM//NONSGML Calendar//EN\r\n";
    $message.=  "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
    $message.=  "X-WR-TIMEZONE:GMT\r\n";
    $message.=  "X-WR-CALNAME:ZCRM\r\n";
    $message.=  "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
    $message.=  "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r\n";
    $message.=  "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    $message.=  "UID:".$uid."\r\n";
    $message.=  "DESCRIPTION:".$desc."\r\n";
    $message.=  "ORGANIZER;CN= Manisha:mailto:manisha.g@careervita.com\r\n";
    $message.=  "DTSTART:20150710T100010Z\r\n";
    $message.=  "DTEND:20150710T110000Z\r\n";
    $message.=  "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Vinod T:mailto:g_manisha@outlook.com\r\n";
    $message.=  "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Vivek J:mailto:manisha.gaidhane8788@gmail.com\r\n";
    $message.=  "LOCATION:CV360\r\n";
    $message.=  "CREATED:20150701T060720Z\r\n";
    $message.=  "LAST-MODIFIED:20150701T060720Z\r\n";
    $message.=  "X-EVENT-OWNER:1563791000000084003\r\n";
    $message.=  "END:VEVENT\r\n";
    $message.=  "END:VCALENDAR";

    Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
        $mailer = new JPhpMailer(true);
        if (Yum::module()->phpmailer['transport'])
            switch (Yum::module()->phpmailer['transport']){
                case 'smtp':
                    $mailer->IsSMTP();
                    break;
                case 'sendmail':
                    $mailer->IsSendmail();
                    break;
                case 'qmail':
                    $mailer->IsQmail();
                    break;
                case 'mail':
                default:
                    $mailer->IsMail();
            }
        else
            $mailer->IsMail();
            $mailer->IsHTML(true);

        $mailerconf=Yum::module()->phpmailer['properties'];
        if(is_array($mailerconf))
            foreach($mailerconf as $key=>$value) {
                if(isset(JPhpMailer::${$key}))
                    JPhpMailer::${$key} = $value;
                else
                    $mailer->$key=$value;
            }

        $mailer->SetFrom($from); 
        $mailer->AddAddress($to); 
        $mailer->Subject = $subject;
        $mailer->Body = $message;
        $mailer->AddCC('testcareervita@gmail.com', 'Person One');
        $mailer->AddCC('testcareervita@yahoo.in', 'Person Two');

        $mailer->ContentType = 'text/calendar';
        $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mailer->addCustomHeader("MIME-version : 1.0");
        $mailer->addCustomHeader('Content-type : text/calendar; name="testcal.ics"; method=REQUEST;');
        $mailer->addCustomHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit'); //to interpret ics file
        $mailer->addCustomHeader("Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage"); 
        $mailer->addCustomHeader('Content-Disposition : inline; filename="testcal.ics"');
        return $mailer->Send(); 
}
```

1. How to send HTML data within same email?
2. Also for outlook .ics file is not getting for download 
   Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You should not add those custom headers - it will just break things.

PHPMailer includes a simple ICS generation class called [EasyPeasyICS](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/extras/EasyPeasyICS.php). It's only very simple, but it does the most important things. For how to use it, refer to [this example in the test suite](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/test/phpmailerTest.php#L1093).

However you're generating it, just stick your ics data into `$mail->Ical` and it will be added to the `multipart/alternative` as a `text/calendar` part alongside the usual `text/html` and `text/plain` parts. This is slightly tricky and unreliable in some clients, and you will probably run into trouble if you try to use attachments at the same time.

Unfortunately PHPMailer doesn't let you build arbitrary MIME structures, and it would get too messy to support iCal parts more comprehensively, especially in the face of broken support in some clients that require messy workaround, as [this issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175) discusses.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, before also i tried to use the same but it was giving error like Notification and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "assertNotEmpty".

Comment: Duh! Don't just copy & paste from the test - it's a test, not usable code! Look at it, see how the ICS class is used.

Comment: Hi i am trying with the same but i am only getting html text in mail and in .ics file ICS file with whole html of my current working page

Comment: $ical = new EasyPeasyICS();
$ical->addEvent('15-07-2015 08:00:00','15-07-2015 17:00:00',"ICS AND HTML","ICS AND HTML","");
$ical->setName('schedule');
$mailer->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'info');
$mailer->addAddress('name@outlook.com', 'Name');    
$mailer->Body = 'This is theHTML part of the email.';
$mailer->AltBody = 'This is the text part of the email.';
$mailer->Subject .= 'EasyPeasyICS iCal';
$mailer->Ical = $ical->render();
$mailer->send();

Comment: So check the return values rather than just assuming they are working.